# Impossible to upload file with buefy upload

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, lumen, buefy

I'm creating a website and now I try to use my upload file system. I test it with postman and it works perfectly. But when I try to use with my website page, it not works.

Backend : I use Lumen
Frontend : I use Buefy

The upload function into UserController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function uploadImageIntoUser(Request $request, $id){

        //try{

            $user = User::findOrFail($id);

            if ($user->id == Auth::id()) {

                $url = json_decode($this->uploadImage($request, $id)->getContent(), true);

                $newRequest = new Request();

                $newRequest->replace(['picture' => $url['data']['image'] ]);

                return $this->update($id, $newRequest);

            }

            return response()->json(['message' => 'You not have the right to do this'], 412);

        /*}catch (\Exception $e){

            return response()->json(['message' => 'User not found'], 404);

        }*/

    }

}
```

The upload function into my Controller.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Galerie;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
   //Upload image

    public function uploadImage(Request $request, $id)
    {

        try{

            $this->validate($request, [
                'folder' => array(
                    'required',
                    'alpha')
            ]);

            $folder = $request->input('folder');

            if(strcmp($folder, "user") !== 0 && strcmp($folder, "article") !== 0 && strcmp($folder, "galerie") !== 0){
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Incorrect folder name : choose between user, article and galerie'], 409);
            }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Incorrect folder name : only in lowercase'], 409);

        }

        $response = null;
        $user = (object) ['image' => ""];

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $original_filename = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $original_filename_arr = explode('.', $original_filename);
            $file_ext = end($original_filename_arr);

            if($folder == 'user'){

                $destination_path = './upload/user/';

            }else if($folder == 'article'){

                $destination_path = './upload/article/';

            }else if($folder == 'galerie'){

                $destination_path = './upload/galerie/';

            }

            $image = time() . '.' . $file_ext;

            if ($request->file('image')->move($destination_path, $image)) {

                if ($folder == 'user') {

                    $user->image = '/upload/user/' . $image;

                }else if($folder == 'article'){

                    $user->image = 'upload/article/' . $image;

                }else if($folder == 'galerie'){

                    $user->image = 'upload/galerie/' . $image;

                    $galerie = new Galerie;
                    $galerie->id = Str::uuid();
                    $galerie->url = $user->image;
                    $galerie->save();

                }

                return $this->responseRequestSuccess($user);
            } else {
                return $this->responseRequestError('Cannot upload file');
            }
        } else {
            return $this->responseRequestError('File not found');
        }
    }

    protected function responseRequestSuccess($ret)
    {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $ret], 200)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }

    protected function responseRequestError($message = 'Bad request', $statusCode = 200)
    {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'error' => $message], $statusCode)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }

}
```

Call my upload system from my profile page (called connexion.vue)

```html
<template>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <p id="center-text" class="title">Informations Personnelles</p><br>

            <b-notification v-if="error" type="is-warning">
                {{ error }}
            </b-notification>

            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column">
                    <img :src='baseURL + loggedInUser.picture'>
                    <b-field label="Modifier la photo de profil">
                        <b-field class="file is-secondary"  :class="{'has-name': !!file2}">
                            <b-upload v-model="file2" class="file-label" rounded>
                                <span class="file-cta">
                                    <b-icon class="file-icon" icon="upload"></b-icon>
                                    <span class="file-label"><strong>Sélectionner un fichier à envoyer</strong></span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="file-name" v-if="file2">
                                    {{ file2.name }}
                                </span>
                            </b-upload>
                        </b-field>
                    </b-field>
                    <b-button v-if="file2" type="is-secondary" @click="upload">Envoyer</b-button>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p class="title">{{ loggedInUser.pseudo }} <b-button @click="modifyPseudo" icon-right="pencil"/> </p><br v-if="!isModifyPseudo">
                    <form v-if="isModifyPseudo" method="post" @submit.prevent="sendModification">
                        <b-field label="Nouveau nom d'utilisateur" label-for="newPseudo">
                            <b-input id="newPseudo" v-model="newPseudo"></b-input>
                        </b-field>
                        <div class="control">
                            <button type="submit" class="button is-secondary is-fullwidth">
                                <strong>Modifier</strong>
                            </button>
                        </div><br>
                    </form>
                    <p class="subtitle">Adresse mail : {{ loggedInUser.email }} <b-button @click="modifyMail" icon-right="pencil"/> </p>
                    <form v-if="isModifyMail" method="post" @submit.prevent="sendModification">
                        <b-field label="Nouvelle adresse mail" label-for="newMail">
                            <b-input id="newMail" v-model="newMail" type="email"></b-input>
                        </b-field>
                        <div class="control">
                            <button type="submit" class="button is-secondary is-fullwidth">
                                <strong>Modifier</strong>
                            </button>
                        </div><br>
                    </form>
                    <p class="subtitle">Nationalité : {{ loggedInUser.nationality }} <b-button @click="modifyNation" icon-right="pencil"/> </p>
                    <form v-if="isModifyNation" method="post" @submit.prevent="sendModification">
                        <b-field label="Nouvelle nationalité" label-for="newNation">
                            <b-select expanded v-model="newNation" icon="earth">
                                <option
                                    v-for="nation in nationalities"
                                    :value="nation.code"
                                    :key="nation.id">
                                        {{ nation.name }}
                                </option>
                            </b-select>
                        </b-field>
                        <div class="control">
                            <button type="submit" class="button is-secondary is-fullwidth">
                                <strong>Modifier</strong>
                            </button>
                        </div><br>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import countries from '@/assets/countries.json';
export default {
  middleware: 'auth',
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['isAuthenticated', 'loggedInUser'])
  },
  data (){
      return {
          baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/',
          isModifyPseudo: false,
          isModifyMail: false,
          isModifyNation: false,
          newPseudo: '',
          newMail: '',
          newNation: '',
          nationalities: {},
          error: '',
          file2 : null,
      }
  },
  methods: {
      modifyPseudo() {
        if(!this.isModifyPseudo){
            this.newPseudo='';
        }
        this.isModifyPseudo = !this.isModifyPseudo;
      },
       modifyMail() {
        if(!this.isModifyMail){
            this.newMail='';
        }
        this.isModifyMail = !this.isModifyMail;
      },
      modifyNation() {
        if(!this.isModifyNation){
            this.newNation='';
        }
        this.isModifyNation = !this.isModifyNation;
      },
      async upload(){
          try{
              var formData = new FormData();
              console.log(this.file2);
              formData.append('image', this.file2);

              const newPicture = await this.$axios.post('users/' + this.loggedInUser.id + '/picture', formData, {
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
            });
              console.log(newPicture);

              const updatedUser = {...this.$auth.user}
              updatedUser.picture = newPicture.data.picture;
              this.$auth.setUser(updatedUser)

              this.file2 = null;
          }catch (error){
              //this.error = error.response.data.message;
              console.log(error.response);
          }
      },
      async sendModification(){
          try{
            if(this.isModifyPseudo){
                const newPseudo = await this.$axios.put('users/' + this.loggedInUser.id, {
                    pseudo: this.newPseudo
                });

                const updatedUser = {...this.$auth.user}
                updatedUser.pseudo = newPseudo.data.pseudo;
                this.$auth.setUser(updatedUser)

                this.newPseudo = '';
                this.isModifyPseudo = false;
            }
            if(this.isModifyMail){
                const newMail = await this.$axios.put('users/' + this.loggedInUser.id, {
                    email: this.newMail
                });

                const updatedUser = {...this.$auth.user}
                updatedUser.email = newMail.data.email;
                this.$auth.setUser(updatedUser)

                this.newMail = '';
                this.isModifyMail = false;
            }
            if(this.isModifyNation){
                const newNation = await this.$axios.put('users/' + this.loggedInUser.id, {
                    nationality: this.newNation
                });

                const updatedUser = {...this.$auth.user}
                updatedUser.nationality = newNation.data.nationality;
                this.$auth.setUser(updatedUser)

                this.newNation = '';
                this.isModifyNation = false;
            }
          }catch(error){
              this.error = error.response.data.message;
          }
      }
  },
  async mounted() {
        try {
            this.nationalities = countries;
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    img {
        border-radius: 50%;
        object-fit: cover;
        height: 10em;
        width: 10em;
    }
    .container #center-text {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .file-label strong{
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

And when I click on the send button, because I don't catch the error, it sends the error 500.

EDIT :

So into my upload function into my profile page (called connexion.vue) :
I replace that

```js
var formData = new FormData();
              console.log(this.file2);
              formData.append('image', this.file2);
```

by this

```js
var formData = new FormData();
              console.log(this.file2);
              formData.append('image', this.file2);
              formData.append('folder', 'user');
```

and into my Controller.php file I replace this :

```php
if($folder == 'user'){

                $destination_path = './upload/user/';

            }else if($folder == 'article'){

                $destination_path = './upload/article/';

            }else if($folder == 'galerie'){

                $destination_path = './upload/galerie/';

            }
```

by this

```php
if($folder == 'user'){

                $destination_path = storage_path('../public/upload/user/');
                //$destination_path = './upload/user/';

            }else if($folder == 'article'){

                $destination_path = storage_path('../public/upload/article/');
                //$destination_path = './upload/article/';

            }else if($folder == 'galerie'){

                $destination_path = storage_path('../public/upload/galerie/');
                //$destination_path = './upload/galerie/';

            }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the error with some logs?

Comment: I try to use dd into the php file to find the error, but I didn't know how I can use it

Comment: A 500 is an Internal Server Error which usually indicates that the server has been misconfigured. If you're not seeing a PHP error then the request is either malformed or the server is not configured properly which means the request is not even hitting PHP. What Web Server software are you using (NGINX, Apache httpd, Web Sphere, Other?). Check the logs of the actual web server software to see why there is a 500 error.